# How do I configure the beefy parameter in the spec?

Tags: private-network, rococo-local, polkadot-local, beefy

after reading and executing [Start a private network](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/private-network/), I managed successfully same exercise with polkadot-local spec chain base.

Now I would like to do same exercise but this time with rococo local spec but here I'm locked cause I don't know how to add new keys in the session part of the file. Indeed, I don't see any helpfull documentation which explain what is the `beefy` protocol and how to fill it...

Indeed it seems rococo spec add this protocol when comparing sessions sections between polkadot-local and rococo-local spec :

*Polkadot local session section :*

```
      "session": {
        "keys": [
          [
            "5GNJqTPyNqANBkUVMN1LPPrxXnFouWXoe2wNSmmEoLctxiZY",
            "5GNJqTPyNqANBkUVMN1LPPrxXnFouWXoe2wNSmmEoLctxiZY",
            {
              "grandpa": "5FA9nQDVg267DEd8m1ZypXLBnvN7SFxYwV7ndqSYGiN9TTpu",
              "babe": "5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY",
              "im_online": "5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY",
              "para_validator": "5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY",
              "para_assignment": "5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY",
              "authority_discovery": "5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY"
            }
          ],
          [
            "5HpG9w8EBLe5XCrbczpwq5TSXvedjrBGCwqxK1iQ7qUsSWFc",
            "5HpG9w8EBLe5XCrbczpwq5TSXvedjrBGCwqxK1iQ7qUsSWFc",
            {
              "grandpa": "5GoNkf6WdbxCFnPdAnYYQyCjAKPJgLNxXwPjwTh6DGg6gN3E",
              "babe": "5FHneW46xGXgs5mUiveU4sbTyGBzmstUspZC92UhjJM694ty",
              "im_online": "5FHneW46xGXgs5mUiveU4sbTyGBzmstUspZC92UhjJM694ty",
              "para_validator": "5FHneW46xGXgs5mUiveU4sbTyGBzmstUspZC92UhjJM694ty",
              "para_assignment": "5FHneW46xGXgs5mUiveU4sbTyGBzmstUspZC92UhjJM694ty",
              "authority_discovery": "5FHneW46xGXgs5mUiveU4sbTyGBzmstUspZC92UhjJM694ty"
            }
          ]
        ]
      },
```

*Rococo local session section :*

```
"session": {
  "keys": [
    [
      "5GNJqTPyNqANBkUVMN1LPPrxXnFouWXoe2wNSmmEoLctxiZY",
      "5GNJqTPyNqANBkUVMN1LPPrxXnFouWXoe2wNSmmEoLctxiZY",
      {
        "grandpa": "5FA9nQDVg267DEd8m1ZypXLBnvN7SFxYwV7ndqSYGiN9TTpu",
        "babe": "5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY",
        "im_online": "5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY",
        "para_validator": "5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY",
        "para_assignment": "5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY",
        "authority_discovery": "5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY",
        "beefy": "KW39r9CJjAVzmkf9zQ4YDb2hqfAVGdRqn53eRqyruqpxAP5YL"
      }
    ],
    [
      "5HpG9w8EBLe5XCrbczpwq5TSXvedjrBGCwqxK1iQ7qUsSWFc",
      "5HpG9w8EBLe5XCrbczpwq5TSXvedjrBGCwqxK1iQ7qUsSWFc",
      {
        "grandpa": "5GoNkf6WdbxCFnPdAnYYQyCjAKPJgLNxXwPjwTh6DGg6gN3E",
        "babe": "5FHneW46xGXgs5mUiveU4sbTyGBzmstUspZC92UhjJM694ty",
        "im_online": "5FHneW46xGXgs5mUiveU4sbTyGBzmstUspZC92UhjJM694ty",
        "para_validator": "5FHneW46xGXgs5mUiveU4sbTyGBzmstUspZC92UhjJM694ty",
        "para_assignment": "5FHneW46xGXgs5mUiveU4sbTyGBzmstUspZC92UhjJM694ty",
        "authority_discovery": "5FHneW46xGXgs5mUiveU4sbTyGBzmstUspZC92UhjJM694ty",
        "beefy": "KWByAN7WfZABWS5AoWqxriRmF5f2jnDqy3rB5pfHLGkY93ibN"
      }
    ]
  ]
},
```

Can come of you tell me moe about this `beefy` protocol ?

Thank you :)

---

Edit: don't really know why this question has been closed. Looking feedbacks from substrate it tells it should tells about one subject. Well let me know if you see other subject than `beefy` protocol here.

[image]

Last but not least, that link provides me answer to that question : https://github.com/paritytech/grandpa-bridge-gadget